# Can we use present verb for past?

Tags: present-simple

In this sentence:

> The captions linking the action appear in R.W. Paul's *Scrooge* (1901) and began occurring more frequently.

in my understanding, the verb *appear* indicates an action in the past, but why it is conjugated in simple present tense?

Comment: Without further context, this looks a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Appear" is not describing an action in the past, but the present state.  If you look in a copy of Scrooge *today* you will the captions linking the action. The captions appear, now!

The shift from present to past is a little awkward, but may be unavoidable.